# How to use unserscore.js with HTML helpers in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to append dynamically input fields in the form using an underscore.js library in Asp.Net MVC 5.

Below is my HTML code.

```
<script type="text/template" id="template">
<div class="row" id="row-<%= No%>">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
        <label>Account</label>
        @Html.DropDownList("[<%= No%>].AccountId", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "Id", "AccountName"), new { @class = "form-control select2" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label>Type</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="[<%= No%>].Type">
            <option>Dr</option>
            <option>Cr</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="[<%= No%>].Amount" min="1" required />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm adjust-btn" onclick="RemoveRow('row-<%= No%>')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and below is my Js Code.

```
var rowNo = 2;
$("#btn-AddAccount").click(function () {
    var html = $("#template").html();
    var temp = _.template(html);
    var value = {
        No: rowNo
    };
    var tmpl = temp(value);
    $("#div-accounts").append(tmpl);
    rowNo += 1;
});
```

Now when "Add-Account" button clicks above HTML template append in the form. There is variable in HTML code "<% =No%>", it counts the row no. I have also placed the same variable in HTML helper's first parameter. 
When it renders in browser there should be like

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="[1].AccountId"</select>
```

But it renders like

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="[<%= No%>].AccountId"</select>
```

Comment: Are you in process converting from ASPX view to Razor? `<%= No %>` should be converted to `@Html.Raw(No)` or just `@No` in Razor (https://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/).

Comment: "<%= No%>" variable is populating from js code. For simple HTML code this variable is working fine. But in HTML helper its not

Comment: Are you saying I have to write like this?                               `@Html.DropDownList("[@No].AccountId", new SelectList(ViewBag.Accounts, "Id", "AccountName"), new { @class = "form-control select2" }) `

Comment: Can you correct the question title so that other people with the same problem see it?

Comment: Can you please suggest me a better suggestion?

Comment: I think you can look at this: http://underscorejs.org/#template (sorry for misleading `<%= ... %>` which I thought as ASPX syntax before), and how you're assigning value to `rowNo`?

Comment: I have updated the Js portion in my question. There you can see the assigning value to `rowNo`